# Spring Security database missing enabled column

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to implement spring security in spring boot application using db2 database. My Db2 table doesn't have 'enabled' **boolean** column to match default field of interface UserDetails which is being implemented by User class. So hibernate and jpa don't work. Db2 table has only one column **integer** to verify if user is active or not.
Is it possible to bypass this issue by casting this field or change Userdetails interface?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if it would help, but Db2 11.1.1.1 added support for `BOOLEAN` columns in tables

Answer (score 0):

When your class implemented `UserDetails` you need to override `boolean isEnabled();` method.

Let's say your field is `private Integer enabled;` and User is enabled if enabled is `1` or else not enabled.

For this case we can override related method like below:

```
    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled == 1;
    }
```